# reading and printing escape characters from a command line argument (in hex) using C

Tags: c

Background: My current project is coding a tokenizer using C.

The program takes a single string as <s>an argument</s> a command line argument .  The program ignores whitespace, then proceeds to read each character left to right, and categorizes valid tokens by their type as they come. If they're found not to be valid, outputs them as "error".

*If an escape character is encountered, they should be labelled as such, then their value should be printed in hex.*

Since the program reads characters in a String one at a time, I believe the string is simply reading '\' alone, instead of '\t' together as a single character.  I've tried using a lookahead character:

```
if(currentCharacter == '\')
{
//then using an index-lookahead with strcat to combine '\' + 't'
}
```

but I'm not getting the output I expect.
I've also tried using:

```
if( iscntrl(currentCharacter) ){
     printf("escapeChar [0x02%x]\n", currentCharacter);
}
```

But like I said, since the string is reading one character at a time, the output is not correct.  I'm still learning C, so any guidance would be very appreciated.  Let me know if any clarifications are needed.

**Example Input**:
"  Hello2 0x234 2asdf \t"

**Example Output**:
word "Hello2"
hex "0x234"
error "2asdf"
escapeChar "0x09"

Comment: generic advice: use some *parser state*, e.g. a variable you set to 1 when you encounter an escape, so in the next iteration, you know to handle the following character differently and then reset the variable.

Comment: "\t" *in source code* is an abbreviation for the single character HT, or Ctrl-I, or '\t'. In your input string it is two separate characters that in C source would be '\\' and 't'. If you want your command line to interpret those abbreviations, you'll have to do the parsing. Also, beware of what the shell (if any) will substitute for its text escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

`\t` when it appears in a C string, is 1 character not 2. It is the tab character with ASCII code `0x09`

if you want to check if a character is equal to `\` in C you should escape it e.g.

`if (currentCharacter == '\\')`

Comment: That's what I thought as well. But I was confused, when reading the String (one character at a time) '\t' was not recognized by "iscntrl(currentCharacter)".  Perhaps I was mistaken, I'll take another look.

Comment: Yes, in a string defined in your C source. Not in something you get as a command line argument (except, of course, the shell already replaced the escape sequence by a control character)

Comment: `iscntrl('\t');` returns true (nonzero) when I try it.

Comment: I agree that iscntrl('\t') is true.  But in my implementation, the currentCharacter is equal to an index of a String being read.  If the program input is: "hi \t", when I reach index 3, currentCharacter = '\'. It does not equal '\t' as I want it to.

Comment: @FelixPalmen the question states "The program takes a single string as an argument". If that means a command line argument you are on to something.

Comment: @user197236 if you want to check if a character is equal to \ you should use `currentCharacter == '\\'`